# Probability of set inclusion

Tags: probability

Given a set $N$ containing elements for random selection (say marbles in a bag, or something like this). All selections of objects for each subset are uniformly random- Each element has an identical chance of being selected.

Given a random selection of set $X_1 \subseteq N $, and...
Given a random selection of set $X_2 \subseteq N $, and...
$|X_2| < |X_1|$, then...

What is the probability, using known values for $|N|, |X_1|, $ and $ |X_2|$, of $X_2 \subseteq X_1$?

PS- All sets N, X1, and X2 are NON-EMPTY.

Comment: What do you mean by a "uniformly random subset" ? All (non-empty?) subsets are equally likely? Or something else? Are the sizes of the two subsets fixed ahead of time? You need to be a little more precise as to what you have in mind.

Comment: the choice of each element selected is a uniformly random probability- Each element has exactly the same probability of being selected, as opposed to, say, a gaussian (normal) distribution where certain elements have higher chances of being selected. And yes, the sizes are known up front. And Yes, all subsets are non-empty (see last line) and are all equally as likely.

Comment: By "element" do you mean "element of the set N"? What probability does each element have of getting into X1? into X2? How do you insure that the sizes come out right? Or by "element" do you mean "subset of X"?

Comment: > Given a set $N$ containing *elements*
The Elements are from set N

Probability is $1/|N|$ for the first selection, $1/(|N|-1)$ for the second, etc.

Comment: Thanks, so the subsets of the given size are indeed equally likely. Let $K<L$ be given positive integers less than or equal to $n=|N|$. Let $X$ (respectively $Y$) be a randomly chosen subset of $N$ of size $L$ (respectively $K$). The number of equally likely possible choices for $Y$ is $C(n,K)$ and the number of those which are subsets of $X$ is $C(L,K)$. So the probability is $C(L,K) / C(n,K) =[ (L)(L-1)(L-2)....(L-K+1) ] / [ (n)(n-1) .... (n-K+1) ]$.  ($C(a,b)$ denotes binomial coefficient)

Comment: Thanks, Ned- This is exactly the insight I needed. That totally makes sense. Thank you!